# How to cd to directories linked in .lnk files?

Tags: bash, msys

In msys bash in Windows, I'd like to cd to the directory a (Windows native) .lnk links to. These are the standard Windows shortcuts. I want to be able to do this:

```
~ $ cdlnk programs.lnk
/c/Program\ Files/ $
```

I've come this far:

```
strings "$lnk" | grep -A 1 DATA | tail -n 1
```

gives me the path the shortcut links to. However, now I'm stuck. I can either

1. Make an alias in .bashrc - but then I cannot use pipes or pass the parameter to a script, i.e. I cannot run above code.
2. Make a script cdlnk.sh - but then I can only change its cd and not that of the calling shell.

Comment: You can stick your command into a *function* in a file that gets sourced, for example somwhere in `.bashrc` or a file that gets sourced in there.

Comment: Great! That works! Thank you.

Comment: Care to put your comment in an answer? Then I can select it and mark the question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To both be able to process parameters *and* modify the current shell, you can use a [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) in a file that has to be [sourced](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-source), for example `.bashrc`.

For the command you have, the function might look like this:

```sh
cdlnk() {
    strings "$1" | grep -A 1 DATA | tail -n 1
}
```

You could make this a little shorter by using sed instead of grep and `tail`:

```sh
cdlnk() {
    strings "$1" | sed -n '/DATA/{n;p;q;}'
}
```

where `-n` suppresses output, and on a line matching `DATA`, the commands are `n` (get next line into pattern buffer), `p` (print the line), and `q` (exit – no need to look at the rest of the file).